# Joining 2 text files using pandas, 1st text file into header, the 2nd as the body

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am using jupyter and I have 2 text file. dataset.txt and feature_names.txt.
I input the following code.

```
header1 = r'./data/feature_names.txt'
main = r'./data/dataset.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(main, names=[header1])
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WK1v.png)

For some reason it only printed ./data/feature_names.txt although when I print the header it prints fine. But the only issue is when I join it with the main. I'm not sure how to make the header file become a header. I am using the [Jupyter Website](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/02%20-%20Lesson.ipynb) for help but I still don't get it. I was told this would be enough to do solve this problem.

Comment: You need to read the columns names from the file, you are passing header1 that is a string to names.

Comment: what is the format of the ./data/feature_names.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `names` parameter of the `read_csv` function expects an array of names. You instead passed it the name of the file which contains your column names. Try this:

```
header1 = r'./data/feature_names.txt'
header_file = open(header1, 'r')

# Assuming one column name per line
headers = []
for line in header_file:
    headers.append(line.strip())
header_file.close()

main = r'./data/dataset.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(main, names=headers)
```

Comment: @Malpa Be sure to upvote/accept answers that were helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
header1 = r'./data/feature_names.txt' #header1 header2 header3
with open(header1,'r') as file:
    header_values = file.read().split() # you need to read the headers from file
main = r'./data/dataset.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(main, names=header_values)
```